# No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available при тестировании в Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

подскажите пожалуйста как решить данную проблему, в интернете решения не помогли. Вывод консоли при тестировании:

> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>   *************************** Description: A component required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found. Action: Consider
>   defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
>   2020-01-23 13:44:49.179 ERROR 16637 --- [           main]
>   o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while
>   allowing TestExecutionListener
>   [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@e19bb76]
>   to prepare test instance
>   [ua.korzh.test.web.RestControllerTest@52ae997b]
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
>   ~[spring-test-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
>   ~[spring-test-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:95)
>   ~[spring-boot-test-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:79)
>   ~[spring-boot-test-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:54)
>   ~[spring-boot-test-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
>   ~[spring-test-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:98)
>   ~[spring-test-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:337)
>   ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]   at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:342)
>   ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]   at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:337)
>   ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:336)
>   ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]   at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:259)
>   ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]   at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:252)
>   ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]   at
>   java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369) ~[na:na]    at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:251)
>   ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]   at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:29)
>   ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]   at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:106)
>   ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]   at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>   ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]  at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105)
>   ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]   at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
>   ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]   at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:107)
>   ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]  at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>   ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]  at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:107)
>   ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]  at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:75)
>   ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]  at
>   java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540) ~[na:na]
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
>   ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]  at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
>   ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]  at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>   ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]  at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
>   ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]  at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
>   ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]  at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
>   ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]  at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>   ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]  at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
>   ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]  at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
>   ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]  at
>   java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540) ~[na:na]
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
>   ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]  at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
>   ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]  at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>   ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]  at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
>   ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]  at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
>   ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]  at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
>   ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]  at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>   ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]  at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
>   ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]  at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
>   ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]  at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
>   ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]  at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
>   ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]  at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
>   ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]  at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
>   ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]    at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
>   ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]    at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
>   ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]    at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
>   ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]    at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
>   ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]    at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:150)
>   ~[surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]  at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:124)
>   ~[surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]  at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)
>   ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]  at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)
>   ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]  at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)
>   ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]  at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)
>   ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'acountRepository': Cannot create inner bean
>   '(inner bean)#6f5e16cf' of type
>   [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting
>   bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6f5e16cf': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor
>   argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:389)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:134)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1444)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:860)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:126)
>   ~[spring-boot-test-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
>   ~[spring-test-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
>   ~[spring-test-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]    ... 66 common frames
>   omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6f5e16cf': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor
>   argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:691)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:508)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:374)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   ... 84 common frames
>   omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:805)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1278)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:297)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   ... 92 common frames
>   omitted [ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time
>   elapsed: 2.002 s <<< FAILURE! - in
>   ua.korzh.test.web.RestControllerTest Tests run: 1, Failures: 0,
>   Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.002 s <<< FAILURE! - in
>   ua.korzh.test.web.RestControllerTest
>   registerClientIfHisEmailNotExistsTest  Time elapsed: 0.002 s  <<<
>   ERROR!
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'acountRepository': Cannot create inner
>   bean '(inner bean)#6f5e16cf' of type
>   [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting
>   bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6f5e16cf': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor
>   argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6f5e16cf': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor
>   argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available [INFO] Running
>   ua.korzh.test.service.SingUpServiceImplTest

Если убираю аннотацию @EnableJpaRepositories, то ошибок нет, но сервисы возвращают null вместо entity

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему у вас некорректно написан `AcountRepository`

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'acountRepository':

если хотите более точно выложите его код и `ua.korzh.test.web.RestControllerTest` , или ссылку на github